# How to create an executable jar with dependency jars

Tags: java

I have created a java application which depends upon some external jars. Now I want to create an executable jar for my project. Which means if I double click the project then it should execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that easily with Ant:

```
<jar jarfile="MyJar.jar" basedir="bin">
    <manifest>
    <attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/lib1.jar lib/lib2.jar lib/lib3.jar"/>
    <attribute name="Built-By" value="me"/>
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="mypackage.Myclass"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

This will add all the appropriate entries to the Manifest file. In order to be able to run the jar, you also need to create a lib folder and place all the dependency jars there:

```
myjar.jar
lib/lib1.jar
lib/lib2.jar
lib/lib3.jar
```

Comment: The attribute order seems to matter.  The Class-Path needs to appear prior to the Main-Class.

Answer (score 2):

Use eclipse plugin called "fatjar"

**it's update-site**

http://kurucz-grafika.de/fatjar

Just right-click on project and use fatjar option, next step allow you to choose which library will be included in *.jar

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a MANIFEST.MF file to the JAR for your application, (under the META-INF directory - if you use the 'jar' command line tool it will make sure the file ends up in the right place).  It will need to contain two attributes (at least):

- Main-Class: [the fully qualified name of the class in your app that has a main method]
- Class-Path: [the list of JAR dependencies for your application]

More details on manifest files in JAR files can be found here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

If you're using a build tool like [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) you might find that it is able to generate this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the Class-Path attribute in your JAR's Manifest file.

[This page](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) should give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using a packaging tool such as [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) or a wrapper tool such as [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Just to save other time, IzPack is a deployment tool that installs the main jar and the other jars somewhere on a computer, while JSmooth takes all those jars and encapsulates them in with an EXE file so the application can run on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven the assembly plugin will do this for you very simply: [http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/howto.html](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html)

Otherwise you'll need to follow the instructions in the JAR file tutorial: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html and creating a manifest file including your main class as `Main-Class: [classname]` and listing your external jars as `Class-Path: theirJar1 theirJar2` etc.