# running scala apps with java -jar

Tags: java, scala, jar

I got some problems with the java. Check it out.

`sebastian@sebastian-desktop:~/scaaaaaaaaala$ java -cp /home/sebastian/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.8.0.RC3/scala-library-2.8.0.RC3.jar:target/scaaaaaaaaala-1.0.jar scaaalaaa.App`

```
Hello World!
```

That's cool, right, but how bout this:

`sebastian@sebastian-desktop:~/scaaaaaaaaala$ java -cp /home/sebastian/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.8.0.RC3/scala-library-2.8.0.RC3.jar -jar target/scaaaaaaaaala-1.0.jar`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Application
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 at scaaalaaa.App.main(App.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Application
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 ... 13 more
```

Wat the heck? Any idea why the first works and not the 2nd? How do I -jar my scala??

My thanks in advance, brother.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you define -jar the -classpath is ignored:

[Java manual:](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html)

> -jar When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user
>   classes, and other user class path
>   settings are ignored.

You can define the classpath dependencies in the [Manifest metadata](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Main%20Attributes).

The easiest way to start your app is using the scala scripts:

```
scala -classpath target/scaaaaaaaaala-1.0.jar scaaalaaa.App Hello World!
```

Comment: I would prefer a personal Descartes or Newton. :-)

Comment: This is good. But I think the motivation of the question is really, how to deploy and run a Scala app on a machine with only JVM but not Scala or SBT deployed. So it feels like there's no easy way to run it with `java`. Then my question, alternatively, is if it's easy to deploy scala on the target machine? Accordingly to Scala doc, it recommends running scala app via SBT, not even offering a mention on how to properly install scala by itself. So what's the recommendation here?

Comment: @ThomasJung I don't get the joke, please explain!

Answer (score 6):

Simply running

```
scala scaaaaaaaaala-1.0.jar
```

works for me with 2.11.6

Comment: that's not the question.  of course you can run it with scala.  the question is how to run it w/o scala.

Answer (score 6):

use `sbt-assembly` sbt plugin to **produce a jar containing *all* *dependencies***

[sbt-assembly github](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)

e.g. add a line in `project/plugins.sbt`:

`addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.10")`

adjust your `build.sbt` e.g. with

```
mainClass in (assembly) := Some("mypackage.mysubpackage.MyMainClass")
assemblyJarName in assembly := "my_assembly.jar"
```

then build your assembled jar with

`sbt assembly`

and launch it with

`java -jar ./target/scala-2.12/my_assembly.jar`

Et voilà, no class-path this & thats needed any more. only 1 jar.

Answer (score 4):

For an executable jar, the classpath should be in the jar's manifest.  For help on doing that, look through the answers to [Stackoverflow: How to create an executable jar with dependancy jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491990/how-to-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependancy-jars).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way to execute the Scala Executable Jar

- We need scala installed in your system.
- Here first will give the jar path and jar name
- If your code needs any dependency jar then keep all jar in one directory and give a path of this in command like below after the ":".
- At last give your class/object name.

> scala -cp "/your/jar/path/jar_name.jar:/your/dependency/jar/path/*" 
>   SampleCode