# Running multiple Scala apps from one jar on JVM

Tags: scala, jar, jvm, uberjar

I have a Scala application that successfully runs on the JVM using an uber jar via the command: `java -jar myapp.jar`. I need to create a separate, but related Scala job that utilizes many of the same objects/functions/dependencies as the first, making it a great candidate to keep in the same code repository & uber jar. Please note that these Scala jobs do not utilize Spark, so `spark2-submit` is out of the equation.

**Question:** How can I run 2 separate Scala jobs from the same uber jar on the JVM? (I am using Scala 2.11.8 and SBT for jar assembly)

**Additional Context:**

I've already looked into related StackOverflow discussions, namely [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976514/multiple-runnable-classes-inside-jar-how-to-run-them) about specifying Java classes using `java -cp myapp.jar MyClass` and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930146/running-scala-apps-with-java-jar), which only presented the solution of running the Scala equivalent using `scala -classpath myapp.jar MyClass`.

While the `scala -classpath` solution may have worked for the OP of the second linked discussion, I'll be deploying my code to an environment that doesn't have executables for `scala` or `sbt`, only `java`.

Let's say these are the 2 Scala jobs I want to run:

```
// MyClass.scala
package mypackage

object MyClass {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, World!")
  }
}
```

```
// MyClass2.scala
package mypackage

object MyClass2 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, World! This is the second job!")
  }
}
```

Is there a way to run Scala code using `java -cp myapp.jar MyClass`?
I've tried this and receive the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MyClass
```

The main alternative I can think of would be to create a Scala object that serves as a main entry point and takes a parameter to determine which job gets run. I'd like to avoid that solution if possible, but it would allow me to continue using `java -jar myapp.jar`, which has been working fine.

Comment: Do you want to, run the two jobs simultaneously on the same JVM? Run the two jobs simultaneously on different JVMs _(different processes)_? Just being able to select which of the both run? Or just share the code / repository? - Each have a different answer and different consequences.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks for the clarification. I'm looking to run them as separate processes that share the same code base. As you stated, the issue is being able to select which of the two jobs to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a fully qualified name for the `App` instance:

```
java -cp myapp.jar mypackage.MyClass
```