# what is the alternative for Java Jar command to run a jar with scala class

Tags: java, scala, jar, executable-jar

in Java we use java -jar Jarfile

in scala how to run a jar with scala classes

lets sat aaa.jar is my jarname and com.tempObject is my Object.

class

```
object tempObject extends App {
  def cool={    println("Ran Object")  }
}
```

How to run it?

I tried

```
java -cp "spark-gradle-template-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar" org.tempObject
```

error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function0
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function0
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

Can i get help on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [running scala apps with java -jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930146/running-scala-apps-with-java-jar)

Comment: Take a look to [**SBT-Assembly**](https://github.com/sbt/SBT-assembly).