# How to build into Desktop Java?

Tags: playn

So I know you can use ant and mvn to test the project, but I was wondering if there was a way to deploy the project directly as a executable jar or otherwise compile it into a format that can be directly ran? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an executable jar with dependancy jars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491990/how-to-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependancy-jars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are serious about making a launchable desktop program (and especially if its going to be a game), you should use [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to make an exe file that launches the jar. It [isn't hard to use](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html), and it makes the program much more end user friendly

Answer (score 0):

If your project was generated from the 1.7.2 PlayN archetype or newer, that functionality is already built in. Simply invoke:

```
mvn package
```

and a dependencies-included jar file will be generated in:

```
yourgame/java/target/yourgame-java-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

you can test it by running it standalone like so:

```
java -jar yourgame/java/target/yourgame-java-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

If your game was generated via an older PlayN archetype, the you can add the necessary bits to your `java/pom.xml` file by pasting in this in (merging with any existing `<build> <plugins>` blob):

maven-assembly-plugin
        2.4
        
          
            jar-with-dependencies
          
          
            
              ${mainClass}
            
          
        
        
          
            make-assembly
            package
            
              single

Then just run `mvn package` as above to generate the file. Note that you will need to be building against PlayN 1.7.2 or newer as that version is the first one that supported automatic unpacking of the LWJGL native libraries needed to run on the desktop.