# Runnable JAR working but doesn't do its job

Tags: java, jar, executable, runnable, keylogger

It's my first post here so first of all i would like to say hello :)

I wrote my first key logger. It works fine when I launched it from eclipse IDE. When I did runnable JAR file it is working in task manager, but program is not sending emails with key logs, so it is not doing its job. I don't what I could try to solve my problem. I don't know where the problem is. Is it in code? Or maybe some libraries? Any ideas?

I've got there an option to send empty emails, so that is why i know it is not working at all.

Thanks in advance, 
Jacob

Comment: "With Eclipse" - my guess is that you have not packaged your JAR with all its dependencies inside.  It depends on running inside Eclipse.  Look into packaging your dependencies inside your executable JAR and adding to the META-INF classpath.

Comment: You should think about introducing logging into your program. Makes it a lot easier to figure out where things are going wrong. We can't really provide an accurate answer for you without more details.

Comment: @duffymo I have tried both library handling extracting and packaging required libraries and it does not work in any of this scenarios. Can I upload java files for checking? If it goes to META-INF classpath. Never heard of it before. I've got classpath in my folder should I add there something or edit this file?

Comment: You should have Google installed on your machine.  Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491990/how-to-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependency-jars or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033603/how-to-create-a-jar-with-external-libraries-included-in-eclipse

Comment: How would you know if your program is throwing an exception?  What does your code do when exceptions occur?